# How to direct random routing (404) to one view page in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, httprequest

I want to direct random link to only one view except that I've define

> e.g : localhost:8000/abxcdss

It will go to a view or home page.

Comment: Did you mean 404 page redirect to homepage?

Comment: yes.. is there any way to do it?  or direct to new blade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution #1 - Via Exception Handler (404)

***`app/Exceptions/Handler.php`***

```php
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

//

public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
        return redirect('/');
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

#### Solution #2 - Via Route

***`routes/web.php`***

```php
// Last line!

Route::any('{any}', function () {
    return redirect('/');
});
```